# Is there a Stack Exchange section FOR vague and rambling questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I love Stack Exchange and really hope to see it evolve, maybe into a helper page for sites like Wikipedia. One of the problems I have as a user is the kinds of questions I generally have are for lists of answers, or to get a vague and rambling set of answers to dig through and collect the pieces I'm looking for. For instance, it would be nice to ask for a list of great food websites (as an example only) and then get a listing of these sites.

I'm wondering if there is a sub-section or side-section of Stack Exchange that offers this kind of back-and-forth that is restricted on the Stack Exchange topics normally? I get that sites like facebook offer this to one degree or another, and message boards, etc. But none of those sites have the indexing, tagging, searchability, and referencing options that Stack Exchange does. So I'm hoping that there is a Stack Exchange-approved model for this question that I just wasn't aware of yet.

Comment: I like the way you asked this in the form of a vague and rambling question

Comment: Yes there is. Go to one of the science based sites and tag it with "soft-list" or "soft-question" and you're golden.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Software Recommendation SE site *is* designed to get lists of answers.  But on a very narrow subject.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is a sub-section or side-section of stackexchange that offers this kind of back-and-forth that is restricted on the stackexchange topics normally?

No, there isn't. We do have chat rooms, where the rules are more relaxed, but that's about it.

---

The kind of question you are discussing (things like book recommendations) are simply not suitable for our format and our goal of curating good questions and answers - answers that will stand the test of time.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no such site. Vague questions are closed as "too broad" or "unclear what are you asking" on every site of Stack Exchange Network and it is good. Stack Exchange is not social network, so don't compare it with Facebook or Twitter. There you should understand what you are asking, think your question over before you post it. Because Stack Exchange "prefers questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed".